# Less css parse error on mixin

Tags: wordpress, debugging, twitter-bootstrap, less, mixins

I'm using wp-less with wordpress and the Twitter Bootstrap plugin from iControlWP.

The mixin is taken by the bootstrap grid docs to add grid style to elements http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-less:

```
// Generate the extra small columns

.make-xs-column(@columns; @gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {
    position: relative;
    // Prevent columns from collapsing when empty
    min-height: 1px;
    // Inner gutter via padding
    padding-left:  (@gutter / 2);
    padding-right: (@gutter / 2);

    // Calculate width based on number of columns available
    @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
        float: left;
        width: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
    }
}
```

When I load wordpress I receive this error:

> parse error: failed at `.make-xs-column(@columns; @gutter:
>   @grid-gutter-width) {`

If cancel this code block the error pass to the next similar mixin function `.make-sm-column(@columns; @gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {`

Strangely enough, if I pass that code to http://lesstester.com/ it shows no error.

What's going on?

Comment: It is also worth noting that [wp-less states it is using LESSPHP 0.4.0](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-less/), yet if I go set up a test case on [their compiler online](http://leafo.net/lessphp/), I get no error with that code. This seems to indicate that the error is within the wp-less or wordpress itself parsing, not the LESSPHP behind it.

Comment: uhm... can't understand why... never had problem before. maybe this could be the problem? http://leafo.net/lessphp/changelog.html (read the warning)

Comment: No, the selector syntax that link refers to is not even contained in your problem code. Also, as I noted, it compiles fine in the LESSPHP online compiler, so the issue does not seem to be at the level of the less parsing to css, but of wordpress parsing the less file.

Comment: I switched from a github downloaded version of wp-less to the plugin one. Now it doesn't read my .less file at all -___-

Comment: are you sure the arguments are valid using semi-colons ?

Comment: Ok it was an upgrade problem. Once put the plugin I had to use $WPLessPlugin = WPLessPlugin::getInstance(); and $WPLessPlugin->processStylesheets();

Comment: @Kursion: "Yes," for LESS anyway. [Read down](http://www.lesscss.org/#-parametric-mixins) at "Mixins with Multiple Parameters"

Comment: @Bakaburg: So are you saying that once upgraded, it fixed not only the reading of the `.less` file itself, but also fixed the issue with this mixin call (your original question)?

Comment: Yep, now it's fixed. Probably I should write an answer to close the topic.

Answer (score 0):

`.make-xs-column(@columns; @gutter: @grid-gutter-width)` change to:

```
.make-xs-column(@columns, @gutter: @grid-gutter-width)
```

Comment: And I don't think that vars can accept another vars as default. But I can be wrong. So let it be the commet.

Comment: While it is possible that is an issue for some reason in this case, that is not a problem with LESS. Since [version 1.3.2](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#132) the semicolon has been allowed, and is [now recommended](http://www.lesscss.org/#changes): "Parameters are either _semicolon_ or _comma_ separated. It is recommended to use _semicolon_. The symbol comma has double meaning: it can be interpreted either as a mixin parameters separator or as css list separator. Using comma as mixin separator makes it impossible to use comma separated list as an argument."